# Get the sum of all keys in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

How would I get the sum of keys if they have different values in ruby?

```
{"dog"=>1, "cat"=>3, "fish"=>5} = 9
```

Comment: You mean, that if keys have same value then those keys needs to be ignored from sum?

Comment: You want to sum values, not keys. "...if they have different values..." is unclear but inconsistent with the answer you selected, which sums all values without reference to their magnitudes. You need to edit the question (including the title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in your example are strings, the values are integers. If you want the sum of the integers you can do `hash.values.sum`:

```
{"dog"=>1, "cat"=>3, "fish"=>5}.values.sum
#=> 9
```

Comment: my bad, i realized it's not an array. Can I still do this?

Comment: @lost9123193 Is this what you want ?

Comment: ...or `hash.sum(&:last)` to make a single pass and avoid the creation of a temporary array. No guarantee it will be faster, however.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Interesting, I didn't know `#first`/`#last` had that effect on hashes. Thanks!

Comment: We have `obj.sum(&:last)`. The first thing any `Enumerable` method does is convert its receiver to an enumerator (if it is not already one): `enum = obj.is_a?(Enumerator) ? obj : obj.each`. As `sum` has a block it directs `enum` to generate elements that `sum` passes to its block (`{ |a| a.last }`. The doc [Hash#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) does not clarify what elements are generated by the enumerator it returns, but it is easily seen they are 2-element arrays of key-value pairs `enum = {a: 1, b:2}.each; enum.next #=> [:a, 1]; enum.next #=> [:b, 2]`.